# Integrating MarkItUp rich text editor preview with ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, markup, bbcode, markitup

I'm testing out the [MarkItUp! rich text editor](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/) in a MVC app, and everything is working great with the exception of the preview.  In the settings (set.js), there is a `previewParserPath` property ("path to your [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bbcode) parser").  I'm not exactly sure what this is looking for in terms of proper integration with the MVC app.

I believe that this property is what allows the rendering of the text to appear as HTML rather than `[code][/code]` etc.

In my controller, I have created the following:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public String ParseCode(string toBeParsed)
{
    return BBCode.ToHtml(toBeParsed);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `previewParserPath` to `/ControllerName/ParseCode`?

Comment: No I haven't. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the MarkItUp [documentation](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/documentation/)

> previewParserPath
>   string > path
>   You can set path of your own parser to preview the result of markup langages other than html. If this property is setted, built-in preview will be overrided by your own preview script. 
>   Use ~/ for markItUp! root.
>
> previewParserVar
>   string > default: data
>   Name of the var posted with the editor content to the parser defined above.

So I assume you set `previewParserPath` to `/MyController/ParseCode` where `MyController` is the controller with your parsing action. Also, set `previewParserVar` to `toBeParsed`

Note: I'm not sure if MarkItUp does an `POST` or `GET` to the parser, so I would remove the `AcceptVerb[HttpVerbs.Get]` from your action. I would assume it uses `POST` though.

Comment: Sweet!  I corrected the previewParserPath to use the "/" instead of "\" above!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem recently and decided just to override the preview button click with a jQuery handler that grabs the preview html via AJAX from my own WebMethod and writes the resulting HTML into a jQuery UI Dialog.